# How to upload pdf / Xls / docx to Firebase in android Studio?

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I want to upload any type of document to the Firebase.
Also, we have to fetch the document from the local storage.
Can anyone tell how to achieve this?
I tried using StartActivityForResult() but it is deprecated and does not help at all.

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have already seen this resource but it is for Uploading Images and I want to upload doucment type. How to upload it?

Comment: In the exact same way. The upload operation itself isn't tied to the type of the file.

Comment: As I am a beginner, understanding flows and coroutines is not easy for me. Though, I am simple putting intent data inside StorageReference via putFile(uri_name) method and the pdf's and images are uploading now to the firebase storage. But when I upload docx or xls extension files, it stores it non-readable format.
It stores as -> 
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
format.
How can I upload it in readable format i.e. xls and docx?